# 'Here' as subject..... Grammatically correct or not

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Can I say  :  "Here are your shoes" ( if we've found the shoes here )? Can 'HERE' be used in this way? 
 And can I say :  "Here these are" (just like : "here it is")?

Answer (score 8):

*Here* is not the subject: it's the ordinary locative moved to the front for emphasis. The subject is *your shoes*.

*Here is/are X* is fine, but it doesn't mean quite the same thing as *Your shoes are here*—it's used primarily when you hand *X* to the hearer:

> Here are your shoes; I found them under the table.
>   Here's your book; thanks for lending it to me!

And we wouldn't ordinarily say *Here these are* (unless we had to distinguish *these* from some other *X*, "those *X*"); we use the 'personal' pronoun *they*, just as in *Here it is*:

> Here they are; I found them under the table.

Comment: Maybe this is TMI for this site, but *here* is not a subject in this instance.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Not TMI at all. Had StoneyB noticed the title, he would have explained that _here_ is  the locative predicate.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake and P.E.D -- Thanks for pointing out my oversight. I'll fix it.